# How to avoid XmlSerializer failure if process environment is too large?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, process

I ran into a strange problem last week. A call to `new XMLSerializer(typeof(MyType))` crashed with an ExternalException, telling me that csc.exe could not be executed.
After some investigation I found that this exception only occurs if the process environment size reaches a "critical" limit. I created a little sample application to verify that reason.

```
namespace EnvironmentTester
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FillProcessEnvironmentBlock(false);
            SerializeDataObject();
        }

        private static void SerializeDataObject()
        {
            var dto = new DataObject {Name = "MyDto"};

            try
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(dto.GetType()); // throws exception
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter.Null, dto);

                Console.WriteLine("No exception occured.");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occured : " + e.GetType());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void FillProcessEnvironmentBlock(bool fillToMax)
        {
            var currentEnvVarIndex = 0;
            var environmentSize = GetEnvironmentSize();

            int criticalEnvironmentSize = fillToMax ? 30692 : 30691;

            while (environmentSize < criticalEnvironmentSize)
            {
                var envVarName = "Env" + currentEnvVarIndex;
                var envVarValueLength = (criticalEnvironmentSize - environmentSize - envVarName.Length - 2) % 32000;
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(envVarName, new string('a', envVarValueLength));
                currentEnvVarIndex++;
                environmentSize = GetEnvironmentSize();
            }
        }

        private static int GetEnvironmentSize()
        {
            var envVars = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
            int environmentSize = 0;


            foreach (string envKey in envVars.Keys)
            {
                environmentSize += envKey.Length;
            }

            foreach (string envVar in envVars.Values)
            {
                environmentSize += envVar.Length;
            }

            environmentSize += 2*envVars.Keys.Count; // add the '=' and the '\0'

            return environmentSize;
        }

        public class DataObject
        {
            [XmlAttribute("ObjectName")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

If `FillProcessEnvironmentBlock` is called with parameter false, the critical size is not reached, if it's called with true, the ExternalException is thrown. I tested it on two different WindowsXP 32bit SP2 machines, with the same result.

I know that csc.exe is called to create a temporary assembly used to read/write the xml file. But I don't know why the call to csc.exe fails if the process environment is too large.

Does anyone know the reason for this exception? And how can I work around it (if I don't want to write my own xml serialization)?  Are there any other known problems causeed by a process environment that's too large?

Comment: Is your original app actually writing ~30,000 environment variables?

Comment: No, but the environment the app is running in might reach this size because it uses extensive batch scripts to setup it's parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can precompile serializers using [Sgen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(VS.80).aspx) tool or MSBuild [Sgen task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164303.aspx)

Comment: I don't know which classes might be stored in the xml, as this is a generic serialization of a type T that is provided by other assemblies.